# Canning chow chow

Tags: food-safety

I canned 5 jars of chow chow about 1 1/2 weeks ago and just realized I forget to put them in
a water bath after the canning process. Should I through them out? They did seal.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! There are many different ways of canning, and some may be safe if a step is ommitted, others not. We cannot help you without more information. Please post a description of the canning process you were following, including any instructions for holding times and temperatures at each step, so we can see if it is processed enough. You may still save those jars :)

Comment: I boiled the jars and lids @ 180 degrees for 10 minutes. Cooked chow chow for 30 minutes, filled jars, removed air bubbles, wiped top of jar, put on lids and bands.

Answer (score 4):

Chow chow has enough acid and salt in it that you wouldn't need to pressure can it, however in order for it to be safe long-term you would need to process the jars in boiling water. If you haven't done this then your only option after a week and a half would be to throw them out.